# Change content of all elements having same class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a few text elements on the page associated with the class `.currency-text`. I want to format the value of these elements with 3 digit comma separate.

I have already created a function named `formatText()` to format text.

```
function formatText(x) {
   return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

How do I traverse through the document and format all the text elements which have the class `.currency-text`. I am new to DOM manipulation and don’t know what is the efficient way to do it.

Comment: Have you investigated querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate over them applying the formatted text to each element.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.currency-text');

elements.forEach(el => {
  el.textContent = formatText(el.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you can find all elements associated with that class `.currency-text` and iterate on that returned list. Something is like:

```
let elements = $(document).find('.currency-text');
elements.each((e) => { e.innerText = formatText(e.innerText); });
```